# Light trajectory

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, curvature, geodesics

We have observed stars where "we should not"
Some people say that gravity can alter light trajectory.
Some people say that gravity actually alter the space on which light travels.

Which one is correct?

Comment: There are two meanings of 'trajectory' in this context. The answer to your question depends on which one you mean.

Comment: Some people might even say that both are correct.

Comment: Strictly speaking what "people say" is completely irrelevant. The only thing that is relevant is what nature does. Can you observe stars? Yes. Are they right now where a straight line from your eye to the point in the sky where the star seems to be points to? No. Do we understand how to compute the deviation? For the most part.

Answer (score 2):

If I take a plane to the equator, and travel east until I come back to where I started, have I travelled in a curved path or a straight line?

Comment: +1 for answering with a question. And a very, very relevant and applicable question.